# php fopen ftp_get changing owner/group - sometimes - why?

Tags: php, permissions, ftp, fopen

On my php host, I have a script that is run by a cron job that opens/overwrites a file from a remote ftp server.  It works most of the time, but I am finding that when it initially creates the file, the owner/group are "736/736", but at some point the owner and group change to "99/99".  Problem is I start running in to permissions issues  - here is the code:

```
$local = fopen("/mypath/myfile.txt","w");
$result = ftp_fget($conn_id, $local,"remotepath/remotefile.txt", FTP_BINARY);
fclose($local);
```

I am using this same code to pull down a bunch of files.
It does not happen to all the files.  This original file is never touched again, except for a 'read' type fopen ("r").

I do not think it is the ftp_fget, as I have a different script, also run by cron that creates text files via an fopen "w", and SOME of those files are also owner "99/99".

Any thoughts?  Could this be a config problem on the isp's side?  If so, what do I tell them?   When I tell them my owner/group are wrong, they totally reset my entire ftp directory - permissions,owner, etc.  which is a pain.

Comment: Which users are 736 and 99 (look in /etc/passwd)?  What do you mean by "at some point" - between the fopen() and the ftp_fget() ?  What user is the Cron script running as?  If you're running the same script through Apache this could explain the 2 users - one for Cron and one for Apache.

Comment: what I mean is that it does not seem to happen right away, or for example, I have a dozen files that are currently fine (736).   I would think if there were a problem it should create all the files as "99/99" (nobody/apache).     I am not sure about the cron user - this is a hosting provider, so I do not have access to everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Group UID 99 and Owner UID 99 is `Nobody` or `apache`. This is the same for all folders created by the file system. So, when cron job runs, the files are owned by `apache`.

**Solutions:**

1. You can ask your webhosting provider to fix these things.
2. Convert all files that it's going to read/write to 777. If files are 777, it usually does not try to change permission. However, if new files are created, they will again be owner by 99.